# build_association with has_many Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I want to build associated records for non-persisten record in rails.

Let's say I have these models:

```
class Post
   has_many :comments
end
```

I want to do something like this:

```
p = Post.new(text: 'Some post')
p.build_comment(content: 'some comment')
```

It says

```
undefined method `build_comment' for #<Post
```

It works ok for `has_one` association though

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In has_many association, you have to do it like this

```
    p = Post.new(text: 'Some post')
    p.comments.build(content: 'some comment')
```